# Centrar un menu que se encuentra dentro de un contenedor

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy tratando de realizar el siguiente menú con HTML y CSS puro:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta el momento tengo mapeado lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me he encontrado con el siguiente problema: como bien pueden ver, el menú nav está mal alineado; quisiera saber cómo podría alinearlo correctamente tal como está en el diseño.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif;
  font-family: 'DM Sans', sans-serif;
  font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  background: var(--gradiente-2, linear-gradient(90deg, #FF8201 32.60%, #FF1F00 100%));
}

header img {
  padding: 20px 10px 10px 20px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 60px;
}

header .nav__var-left {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
}

header .nav__var-left ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  align-content: center;
  align-self: center;
}

header .nav__var-left li {
  position: unset;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 85%;
}

.nav__var-right {
  width: 30%;
  align-self: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav__var-right .btn {}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <section class="nav__var-left">
      <ul>
        <li>Inicio</li>
        <li>Nosotros</li>
        <li>Productos</li>
        <li>Clientes</li>
        <li>Noticias</li>
      </ul>
    </section>
    <div class="nav__var-right">
      <button class="btn">Cambiar idioma</button>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Usa la propiedad **justify-content**, que indica al navegador como distribuir los elementos hijos de un contenedor **flex** a traves de su *main-axis* [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content):

Voy a usar un SVG para hacer las veces de logo ya que no se encuentra en tu código, el valor especifico para la propiedad es 'space-around', que crea un espacio uniforme entre todos los elementos del contenedor flex, pero colocando la mitad de ese espacio a la izquierda del primer elemento y a la derecha del ultimo.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif;
  font-family: 'DM Sans', sans-serif;
  font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  background: var(--gradiente-2, linear-gradient(90deg, #FF8201 32.60%, #FF1F00 100%));
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

#logo {
  width: 80px;
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#logo svg {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}

header .nav__var-left {
  position: relative;
  width: min-content;
}

header .nav__var-left ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-self: center;
}

header .nav__var-left li {
  position: unset;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 85%;
}

.nav__var-right {
  width: 30%;
  max-width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav__var-right .btn {}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div id="logo">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-apple" viewBox="0 0 16 16"> 
        <path d="M11.182.008C11.148-.03 9.923.023 8.857 1.18c-1.066 1.156-.902 2.482-.878 2.516.024.034 1.52.087 2.475-1.258.955-1.345.762-2.391.728-2.43zm3.314 11.733c-.048-.096-2.325-1.234-2.113-3.422.212-2.189 1.675-2.789 1.698-2.854.023-.065-.597-.79-1.254-1.157a3.692 3.692 0 0 0-1.563-.434c-.108-.003-.483-.095-1.254.116-.508.139-1.653.589-1.968.607-.316.018-1.256-.522-2.267-.665-.647-.125-1.333.131-1.824.328-.49.196-1.422.754-2.074 2.237-.652 1.482-.311 3.83-.067 4.56.244.729.625 1.924 1.273 2.796.576.984 1.34 1.667 1.659 1.899.319.232 1.219.386 1.843.067.502-.308 1.408-.485 1.766-.472.357.013 1.061.154 1.782.539.571.197 1.111.115 1.652-.105.541-.221 1.324-1.059 2.238-2.758.347-.79.505-1.217.473-1.282z"/> <path d="M11.182.008C11.148-.03 9.923.023 8.857 1.18c-1.066 1.156-.902 2.482-.878 2.516.024.034 1.52.087 2.475-1.258.955-1.345.762-2.391.728-2.43zm3.314 11.733c-.048-.096-2.325-1.234-2.113-3.422.212-2.189 1.675-2.789 1.698-2.854.023-.065-.597-.79-1.254-1.157a3.692 3.692 0 0 0-1.563-.434c-.108-.003-.483-.095-1.254.116-.508.139-1.653.589-1.968.607-.316.018-1.256-.522-2.267-.665-.647-.125-1.333.131-1.824.328-.49.196-1.422.754-2.074 2.237-.652 1.482-.311 3.83-.067 4.56.244.729.625 1.924 1.273 2.796.576.984 1.34 1.667 1.659 1.899.319.232 1.219.386 1.843.067.502-.308 1.408-.485 1.766-.472.357.013 1.061.154 1.782.539.571.197 1.111.115 1.652-.105.541-.221 1.324-1.059 2.238-2.758.347-.79.505-1.217.473-1.282z"/> 
      </svg>
    </div>
    <section class="nav__var-left">
      <ul>
        <li>Inicio</li>
        <li>Nosotros</li>
        <li>Productos</li>
        <li>Clientes</li>
        <li>Noticias</li>
      </ul>
    </section>
    <div class="nav__var-right">
      <button class="btn">Cambiar idioma</button>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```